# how do i inherit this public abstract class BusinessBase<TYPE, KEY> : IDisposable where TYPE : BusinessBase<TYPE, KEY>, new()

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm working on a project and can't seem to figure out how to inherit the following base class

```
public abstract class BusinessBase<TYPE, KEY> : IDisposable
    where TYPE : BusinessBase<TYPE, KEY>, new()
```

I thought the following would work but I get a compilation error

```
public class Buisness{
    Business(){}
}

public class BusinessModel : BusinessBase<Business,int>
{

}
```

IDisposable could be any other interface.

Comment: so what's the exact compilation error you get? There's a lot of them.

Comment: Besides the typo in Buisness (sic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class BusinessModel : BusinessBase<Business,int>
```

`BusinessBase.TYPE` is `Buisness`. The specification for `BusinessBase` requires `TYPE` to implement `BusinessBase<>` however you don't show `Buinesss` implementing any class.

It appears that the intent is for the following:

```
public class BusinessModel : BusinessBase<BusinessModel,int>
```

Which would satisfy the requriment that `TYPE` be a `BusinessBase`.

Also note that given the above definition, the following would also work:

```
public class OtherModel : BusinessBase<BusinessModel, int>
```

BTW for reference as to where this would be useful, `IEquatable<T>` is typically implemented for the same type as the class that is implementing it. For instance `Foo : IEquatable<Foo>`. Without looking at the source code for `BusinessBase` I can't say for certain why they are requiring it however.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. Your comment about IEquitable cleared up my confusion.